Can not update database model in VS 2022
I have the following problem:
I cannot update my database model (.edmx).
When I right-click in the model, then “Update model from database” and select my Oracle connection string, the following error occurs:

Image Translation:
Unhandled exception in a component of the application. If you click Next, the application will ignore the error and continue the process.
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection is invalid.
I use the following

.NET v4.6.1
Oracle database

The connection to the database via the API works. I can reach the database with the queries. But not for updates.
Unfortunately, I am unsure about what to do. I have already updated all Nuget plugins and tried using different Connection Strings, but it doesn't seem to help.
Hopefully someone can help me.

Your image text needs to be translated to English.

In order for the error to be understood, it must be translated into English
